# Contar números intermedios en un vector

Tags: c++

```
int aux, suma, cont, medio, max, min = 0;

aux = v[0];
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    if(v[i] > aux){
        max = v[i];
    }
    if(v[i] < min){
        min = v[i];
    }

    if(v[i] < max && v[i] > min){
        suma += v[i];
        cont++;
    }
}
```

Saludos amigos programadores

Tengo una duda como puedo hallar y contar cuantos números intermedios hay en un vector, me sería de gran ayuda sus respuesta soy muy nuevo en programación.

Gracias de antemano

El numero intermedio es aquel que no es ni el menor ni el mayor. Por ejemplo en el arreglo

```
15, 13, 18
```

numero intermedio: 15

Comment: Debes inicializar `ini cont=0;` antes de iniciar el ciclo for, usar signos de agrupación en la tercera condición: `if((v[i] < max) && (v[i] > min)){ ... }` y el resultado se encontrará en cont al salir del ciclo. En cuanto a la suma debe calcularse antes de evaluar las condiciones.

Answer (score 1):

Propongo hacerlo con dos bucles: a) En el primero hallas el maximo y el minimo b) En el segundo cuentas los números intermedios

```
int main(void){
    int aux, suma, cont, medio, max, min = 0;
    
    int n=7;
    int v[n]={85,36,36,12,11,25,59};

    //Encontrar maximo y minimo
    max=v[0];
    min=v[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if(v[i] > max){
            max = v[i];
        }
        if(v[i] < min){
            min = v[i];
        }
    }

    //Contar valores intermedios
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        if(v[i] < max && v[i] > min){
            suma += v[i];
            cont++;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Conteo intermedios: %d\n",cont);
    printf("Suma Intermedios: %d\n",suma);

}
```

Comment: Tiene razon. Editado

Comment: `if(v[i] > aux){` ... ¿qué valor tiene `aux`?

Comment: El código no funciona con `v[] = {10, 10, 67, 0, 0, 15, 7, 8, 34, 67, 67, 0, 0, 34, 34};`

Comment: Si. Tenia un error. Ya quedó corregido

Answer (score 1):

Busca el mínimo, y el máximo. Después cuenta los números que no sean ni el mínimo ni el máximo. La cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) te facilita todas las herramientas que necesitas para ello:

```
int numeros[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

auto minmax = std::minmax_element(std::begin(numeros), std::end(numeros));
auto cuenta = std::count_if(std::begin(numeros), std::end(numeros),
        [&](const auto &numero)
        {
            return numero != *minmax.first && numero != *minmax.second;
        });
```

La función `minmax_element` te busca el mínimo y máximo de una colección de datos, la función `count_if` cuenta los elementos de una colección que cumplan un criterio, en este caso: que no sean ni el mínimo ni el máximo.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible hacerlo con un solo `for`. Lo hacemos es simplemente llevando la cuenta de cuantos veces se repite el máximo y el mínimo y luego restarlo del número de valores ingresados.

Las cuentas las vamos llevando a medida que examinamos cada valor. Si el mínimo o máximo cambiar, volvemos su valor a 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int valores[] = {10, 10, 67, 0, 0, 15, 7, 8, 34, 67, 67, 0, 0, 34, 34};
    int min = valores[0];
    int max = valores[0];
    int n = sizeof(valores) / sizeof(int);
    int mincta = 1;
    int maxcta = 1;
    int suma = min;
    
    for (int i=1; i < n ; i++) {
        
        suma += valores[i];
        
        if (valores[i] == max) maxcta++;
        if (valores[i] == min) mincta++;
        if (valores[i] > max) {
            max = valores[i];
            maxcta = 1;
        } else if (valores[i] < min) {
            min = valores[i];
            mincta = 1;
        }
    }
    int num = n - mincta - maxcta;
    suma = suma - min * mincta - max * maxcta;
    printf("min=%d, max=%d, inter=%d, suma=%d, total=%d", min, max, num, suma, n);
}
```

produce:

```
min=0, max=67, inter=8, suma=152, total=15
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLbaoQwEIbvfYphS0FrbJXdHkDdFyl7IRrbgMbioZQuPrudSeJqXLpBk3Hmy@9vxjz4yPNpuhMyr4aCQ9L1hWgeP4@OI2QPdSak68HZARyU@M6qpuXd@wlSOEchA7pfXhmE6oqeGeDDG4P9QeeXGmX2hzG@aNVCosqsGJ5Wleznnwrt6MQvb0rXlD14mjMIeJZ83mfIR5bwVa4basogrnNqKpsWSA9EGsUgIME34@r782FcSBpKwl8cC@PYgkQJ7gJAmpIbz1jy/fgWKKRnvucGeNSCiz8a9lGujZmqdR40RuBVx7fiiTaxEbc6eCW@aYASd5ZZ9XOoEZAQzHRgPOktpjdqUQg8WCA9rvCvFjVLd4dIel8wqqkVs7xVESmpoG/6rMJox0hQoYzcaARD/JNGZ5r@AA)

Comment: en vez de arrays de tamaño fjio y `sizeof(valores)/sizeof(int)` es preferible usar `std::array` y `array.size()`. Además a partir de C++17 es posible usar `std::size()`

Comment: @eferion. Agradezco el aporte, pero el problema original está en C.

Comment: La pregunta está etiquetada como c++. Otra cosa es que el op haya etiquetado mal la pregunta... pero ese código es perfectamente compatible con c++, luego deberíamos asumir que las reglas propias de c++ están disponibles

Comment: @eferion. Si estaba mal etiquetada, que es un problema generalizado. Por eso nunca las miro.

Comment: Creo que asumes demasiado ... conozco muchos estudiantes primerizos en c++ que programan siguiendo las reglas de C porque no manejan todavía las de C++... pero programan en C++, no en C

Comment: Otra cosa es que añada algo característico de C que no sea posible en C++... eso ya daría alguna pista, pero si el código es compatible con ambos lenguajes deberías asumir que el OP ha etiquetado correctamente

Comment: @eferion. Mejor que publiques tu propia respuesta.

Comment: el uso de `std::size` no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta sino como aporte a tu respuesta. Si no te parece correcto, perfecto, no tienes por qué editar tu respuesta. Pero reetiquetar la pregunta sin estar completamente seguro que está mal etiquetada es otro cantar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113023/discussion-between-candid-moe-and-eferion).

Comment: @CandidMoe *El problema original está en C*, ese código también compila en C++.